# How to Pass the Text field value to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

i have the below script where i want to pass the text field value to a variable 
and display in alert window

```
    <form name='searchdata' id="search_form" >
    <div class="col-xs-4" id="form_submit_ins">
    <label for="usr">Search Instance</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ins" id"searchval" placeholder="Instance Name"><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn" onclick="form_submit();" >Search</button>
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      function form_submit() {
      var item = document.getElementById('searchval').value;
        alert(item);

    }
```

Comment: I think you are looking for .val() not .value. edit: this is jQuery and does not actually fix the issue.

Comment: @Ken the question isn't tagged jquery and `.val()` is not a native method that works on DOM nodes returned from `document.getElementById`...

Comment: @RobM. You are right, I have been running through so many issues today that it seems I have become sloppy. My mistake!

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
id"searchval"
```

Should be:

```
id="searchval"
```

Comment: M Thanks a lot i'm in sleep and could n't realise this .

Comment: No worries, glad to help out :-)

Comment: Can you help me here

Comment: Did that not fix your issue?

Comment: i want to read a json file in Java script and make a search through JSON tree
json file :
{
  "nodes": [
    {"name": "lpcdpapp01.bmwgroup.net", "imagen": "server5.png"},
    {"name": "lpcdpapp02.bmwgroup.net", "imagen": "server5.png"},
    {"name": "lpcdpapp03.bmwgroup.net", "imagen": "server5.png"},
    {"name": "lpcdpapp04.bmwgroup.net", "imagen": "server5.png"}
}

Comment: You should probably post another question, it's going to be difficult to answer and provide code examples in the comments section

Answer (score 0):

id should be equal to searchval i.e `id="searchval"`

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your HTML (does it have two ID fields? Is one missing a "=" sign?

Your code should work if you fix the HTML to:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchval" placeholder="Instance Name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` has two `id`'s, it can only have one `id`

change:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ins" id"searchval" placeholder="Instance Name">
```

To:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchval" placeholder="Instance Name">
```